# Is there a way to search for the most popular music by year in the spotify web API

Tags: spotify

Currently I am trying to make it so that I can make retro playlists just by searching the year. Is there a way in the spotify web api to query for popular music by year. I have looked through the documentation and haven't found it.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can supply release year parameters to the search endpoint of the API.

For example, this query will search for albums released between 1989 and 2013, but excludes 1993.

https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=year:1989-2013%20NOT%20year:1993&type=album

There's currently no way to filter by country, or to sort by popularity.